# En un archivo, buscar líneas que comiencen con el caracter '\'

Tags: c

Como podéis observar en el titulo tengo una duda sobre como buscar equipos con el puerto SMB abierto, por ahora tengo esto en mi programa:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
int main(){
  FILE *f;
  char PC[500];
  system("net view >> smb.txt");
  f = fopen("smb.txt","r");
  while(!feof(f)){
    fgets(PC,50,f);
    printf("%s",PC);
  }

  system("pause");
  exit(0);
}
```

Como podéis observar puedo por lo menos guardar los equipos en un TXT, pero me gustaría saber como hacer que el programa busque en ese documento solo los equipos, es decir, los caracteres que empiezan por \.
Si creéis que hay otra manera mejor de buscar equipos con el puerto SMB abierto os lo agradecería bastante.
Estoy usando C bajo CodeBlocks.
Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda posible.
Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> ¿Cómo hacer que el programa busque [...] los caracteres que empiezan por `\`?

```
while(!feof(f)){
    fgets(PC,50,f);
    if (PC[0] == '\\' && PC[1] == '\\')
    {
        printf("%s es equipo\n",PC);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("%s NO es equipo\n",PC);
    }
}
```

Busca en la primera (índice `0`) y la segunda (índice `1`) posición el carácter `\`. Dado que ese carácter es el que inicia las [secuencias de escape](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C) para poderlo encontrar deberás escaparlo, por eso aparece doble en el código.